# Request for reopening a question on Stack Overflow (cutting sticks)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106595/cutting-a-stick-such-that-cost-is-minimized) has been closed, and it seems several users disagree with that decision.

Could someone examine the question and possibly reopen it?

Comment: It was reopened an hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can go now, and see that it is opened now.

Go to the revisions of the question post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21106595/revisions

It was reopened

> Post Reopened by Sim, Abhishek Bansal, Uwe Keim, wudzik, David Grayson 1H ago (Current time)

It was closed for being too broad, such questions who need a full book to answer the situation and explain the problem are not allowed on Stack Overflow because Stack Overflow is a site where to-the-point discussion is prefered!

So any question which wants (or deserves) a lengthy answer is closed as being **Too Broad!**. The asker has the right to edit it and shorten it down, this way he can tell the community that he is not asking for a whole new edition of a book, but he just wants the viewers to answer this one problem. The question is opened then after review!

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the bother